# convert duplicate rows into new columns MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

Basically I have a MySql table

```
--------    -----------   --------
 cv_id       all_stages    amount
--------    -----------   --------
  12           S1           5
  13           S4           2
  13           S2           1  
  14           S1           3
  14           S3           2
```

I have to write a query so that, based on`cv_id`, I need to have a single entry. And I need to generate few more columns.

What I want is

```
--------    ---------  --------  --------  --------   -------
 cv_id       stage1     stage2    stage3    stage4     total
--------    ---------  --------  --------  --------   -------
  12           S1                                       5
-------------------------------------------------------------
  13                      S2                  S4        3
-------------------------------------------------------------
  14           S1                   S3                  5
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

How should I arrange all stages to the respective `stage` columns based on **cv_id** and totaling the `amount` column?

P.S - I need to execute query to generate new columns

Comment: Show what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good practice to generate columns dynamically. Columns represents common properties for a model, and you will end up with a table that has 100 columns and only one column is used per row. What you are trying to do, can be achieved with another table that links `cv_id` with stages.

For example

```
table cv_stage
Columns: cv_id, stage_name
```

You can then always query `cv_id`'s that have certain stages or any other information you may need.

Comment: True, however this does not really qualify as an answer.